# Expand/Collapse <ul> using toggleclass().next.toggle()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-lists

The following works the way I want it to.  First list item being the title with a plus image.  When you click the image/list-item the second list item expands and the image next to the title changes to a minus image.  However there are some list items that I wanted to have expanded first with the minus-image showing.  when I've removed the style="diplay:none" from the list it properly displays expanded but the image doesn't change.   How can I get the image to display properly.

```
$(function(){
    $('li.plus-image').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("minus-image").next().toggle("fast");
     });     
});



<ul>
    <li class="plus-image">Display title</li>
    <li style="display: none;">
        <ul id="list-filter-items">     
            <li>bullet points</li>
            <li>bullet points</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you can just add class="minus-image" to the ones you want displayed.

Comment: CSS missed here, no needs for declaring $this var

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I set up a jsfiddle like requested http://jsfiddle.net/RwA4Q/1/